# network provider location always returns false(disabled)

Tags: android

So i'm using a virtual device to test some code but the network provider returns false (onProviderDisabled ) even if the wifi is enabled.

By the way the code works when I use the gps provider

```
          Toast.makeText(this, "Guardando ubicacion...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
             LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        locationReal = location;
                        sharedPreferences.edit().putFloat("Latitude",(float) locationReal.getLatitude());
                        sharedPreferences.edit().putFloat("Longitude",(float)locationReal.getLongitude());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ubicacion guardada!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i("YES", "latitude" + locationReal.getLatitude() + "longitude" + locationReal.getLongitude());
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    Log.i("YES", "onProviderEnabled: ");
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    Log.i("NO", "onProviderDisabled: ");
                }
            };
            locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, locationListener, null);
```

location listener should call onProviderEnabled because the virtual device wifi is enabled

Comment: What is the android version of the virtual device?

Comment: a nexus 4 with the 28th android version